# Universal Analytics custom dimensions not showing up

Tags: javascript, google-analytics, dom-events, event-tracking

I'm trying to use custom dimensions to segment users between those who choose button A vs button B to get a certain destination. It might be redundant, but I'm also tracking the button clicks as events as well. This is my code in the html:

```
onclick="ga('set', 'dimension1', 'ClickedSecond'); ga('send', 'event', 'Custom_Navigation', 'click', 'Second', {'hitCallback': function() {document.location = 'second_page.html';}}); return false;" href="second_page.html"
```

Is there a reason why I can't see the results when I try to view these custom dimensions or is there just a time lag?

Comment: You should be able to test if its working by checking the Real-time reports under events.  You will probably have to wait 24 hours before the custom Dimension shows up in the standard reports.

Answer (score 0):

There is a time lag (minimum 4, max 48 hours). The event is not redundant since you need an interaction call (event or pageview) to send a custom dimension.

Comment: Thanks! I thought I already called the hit callback after the tracking event, or do you mean add another one after the custom dimension tracking? Should the tracking event come before the custom dimension?

Comment: Sorry, I have misread your code. I will edit that part from the answer.

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same issue and I had to set the Custom Dimension scope to User in Custom Definitions - Custom Dimensions under the Property column in the Admin tab

[Google Universal Analytics settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D5HVk.png)